# I need a method to get rid of curly brackets in my numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv, curly-braces

I have a 61-by-61 matrix (numpy array) that includes double values (complex numbers).
I want to save my matrix as a CSV file, then use it in Matlab.
But all the elements have curly brackets "( , )".
For example, an element is like:

```
 (3.2-0.4j)
```

I want all my elements to be without curly brackets; I mean:

```
3.2-0.4j
```

Comment: I guess complex numbers are represented between `()` in python. One hack would be to convert everything to `str` and replace the parentheses with blanks.

Comment: Show how you are writing the csv.  With a small sample array. If using `savetxt`, show that you read and understood its complex formating.

Comment: Curly brackets are `{}`, by the way. `()` are parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [213]: arr = np.arange(3.)+np.arange(4)[:,None]*1j                                   
In [214]: arr                                                                           
Out[214]: 
array([[0.+0.j, 1.+0.j, 2.+0.j],
       [0.+1.j, 1.+1.j, 2.+1.j],
       [0.+2.j, 1.+2.j, 2.+2.j],
       [0.+3.j, 1.+3.j, 2.+3.j]])
```

How you attempted it (probably):

```
In [220]: np.savetxt('test.txt',arr, delimiter=',', fmt='%3d')                          
In [221]: cat test.txt                                                                  
 (  0+  0j), (  1+  0j), (  2+  0j)
 (  0+  1j), (  1+  1j), (  2+  1j)
 (  0+  2j), (  1+  2j), (  2+  2j)
 (  0+  3j), (  1+  3j), (  2+  3j)
```

With the complex format as suggested in the docs (an exact copy):

```
In [223]: np.savetxt('test.txt',arr, fmt=' %.4e %+.4ej %.4e %+.4ej %.4e %+.4ej')   
                                                                
In [224]: cat test.txt                                                                  
 0.0000e+00 +0.0000e+00j 1.0000e+00 +0.0000e+00j 2.0000e+00 +0.0000e+00j
 0.0000e+00 +1.0000e+00j 1.0000e+00 +1.0000e+00j 2.0000e+00 +1.0000e+00j
 0.0000e+00 +2.0000e+00j 1.0000e+00 +2.0000e+00j 2.0000e+00 +2.0000e+00j
 0.0000e+00 +3.0000e+00j 1.0000e+00 +3.0000e+00j 2.0000e+00 +3.0000e+00j
```